# Flutter Trying to convert <List<Map<String, dynamic>>> to List<Transactions>

Tags: flutter, sqflite

I'm trying to convert <List<Map<String, dynamic>>> to List

I run a query operation:

```
   static Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> getData(String table) async {
      final db = await DBHelper.database();
      return db.query(table);
   }
```

And calling that method into another class like this:

```
Future<void> fetchAndSetData() async {
    final dataList = await DBHelper.getData('history');
    print(dataList);
    _transactions = dataList
        .map(
          (item) => Transaction(
            id: int.parse(item['id']),
            senderEmail: item['senderEmail'],
            receiverEmail: item['receiverEmail'],
            amount: item['amount'],
          ),
        )
        .toList();
    print('Data: $_transactions');
    notifyListeners();
}
```

After print(dataList). I got the data into the console as expected:

> [{id: 1, senderEmail: andrewjane@service.com, receiverEmail: andrewjane@service.com, amount: 2000.0}, {id: 2, senderEmail: andrewjane@service.com, receiverEmail: andrewjane@service.com, amount: 2000.0}]

But when I printed print('Data: $_transactions'); There is no logs.
_transactions is initialized by an empty array like this
List _transactions = [];

I expect to get the List to contains Transactions.

I'm trying to convert the <List<Map<String, dynamic>>> into List but it is not working, also there is no error.
My Transaction class looks like this:

```
class Transaction {
  final int id;
  final String senderEmail;
  final String receiverEmail;
  final double amount;

  Transaction({
    this.id,
    this.senderEmail,
    this.receiverEmail,
    this.amount,
  });
}
```

Comment: Missing: <List<Map<String, dynamic>>> into List<Transaction>

Comment: What is not working exactly ? What behavior do you expect and what is a misbehavior ? I did not get it what do you mean about _it's not working_. If you have missed something please update the post not comment it

Comment: @MohammadMomeni sorry for unclear post.
When I printed print('Data: $_transactions'); There is no logs. 
And the _transactions is initialized by an empty array like this List<Transaction> _transactions = [];

I expect to get the List to contains Transactions.

Comment: @pskink The code you gave me only works if I comment out the parsing code otherwise no logs. But obviously, that makes no sense to comment out the code and looking at the logs.. It seems like the code is getting stuck while parsing.

Comment: The id is of type String, Transaction model expects to get the id in integer. 
Yeah, exactly no exception is thrown, no logs just after the parsing.

Comment: so `int.parse` throws the exception?

Comment: `int.parse` convert that string to int, that's what my Transaction model expects. I cross-checked that whether am I really getting the string or not by:
`print(item['id'] is String);` and it says true. So, I parse that.

Comment: Again, no exception is thrown.

Comment: ok, so you say that with `id: 0` it works but with `id: int.parse(item['id'])` it does not work and no exception is thrown?

Comment: No.. I mean it works with both without any exception.
I'm not getting any logs for `print('Data: $_transactions');`

Comment: with your data: `main() {var data = [{'id': 1, 'senderEmail': 'andrewjane@service.com', 'receiverEmail': 'andrewjane@service.com', 'amount': 2000.0}, {'id': 2, 'senderEmail': 'andrewjane@service.com', 'receiverEmail': 'andrewjane@service.com', 'amount': 2000.0}];
  var mapped = data.map((d) => d['id']);
  print(mapped);
}` - it will print `(1, 2)` - if no exception is thrown it must simply work

Comment: The problem is resolved, I think the problem was with
`int.parse(item['id'])` because as I said I have checked `print(item['id'] is String);` return true. So, I parse that to int and when I print `print(int.parse(item['id']) is int)` it return false. I don't know why the code was having some strange logs. After stopping and restarting an app, everything did work.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts, and sorry for taking longer.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `fromMap` & `parseTransactionList` methods to your `Transaction` model class.

```
class Transaction {
  final int id;
  final String senderEmail;
  final String receiverEmail;
  final double amount;

  Transaction({
    this.id,
    this.senderEmail,
    this.receiverEmail,
    this.amount,
  });
  
  factory Transaction.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return Transaction(
      id: int.parse(map['id']),
      senderEmail: map['senderEmail'],
      receiverEmail: map['receiverEmail'],
      amount: map['amount'],
    );
  }
  
  static List<Transaction> parseTransactionList(List<dynamic> list) {
    if (list == null) return null;
    
    final transactionList = <Transaction>[];
    for (final item in list) {
      transactionList.add(Transaction.fromMap(item));
    }
    
    return transactionList;
  }
}
```

And to get the transaction list you can do as follows:

```
Future<void> fetchAndSetData() async {
    final dataList = await DBHelper.getData('history');
    print(dataList);
    _transactions = Transaction.parseTransactionList(dataList);
    print('Data: $_transactions');
    notifyListeners();
}
```

You can pass each item(`Map<String, dynamic>`) & create a `Transaction` object from it & add it to the list. This is a very common practice usually to convert json objects to model class object.